# Python project euler

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python, I tried to solve the first problem of project euler with python but I can't figure out a way to find the sum of my variables.

the question was to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
I tried this

```
def f(a):
    for x in range(a):
        if(x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0):
            i = 0
            i = sum({x})
    print(i)
f(100)
```

But it doesn't work, it just gives the value 99, and I have no idea why.I want to adapt it to a function like this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(a):
    foo = []
    for x in range(a):
        if(x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0):
            foo.append(x)
    print(sum(foo))
f(100)
```

Or in one line using list comprehensions:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(some_value) if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)]))
```

Comment: In f(n) where n=100, that code will fail because the x in the loop is only 0 to 99. Also that code does not check if x is still below 1000 in cases where n is 1000 or more.

Comment: ?? Just pass other argument to the function `f(1000)` if you want all numbers bellow a certain value that's right, if you want all values up a value then change `range(a)` to: `range(a + 1)`

Comment: Your code does not check if x is less than 1000, in `for x in range(a)`. According to the problem instruction, x should be below 1000. `the question was to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.`

Comment: Sir, `range` creates a list of all values between some boundaries ex: `range(3)` returns: `[0,1,2]` so there's no need to check if it is bellow 1000. `a` is just the parameter to the function so you can pass other values too, to get what you want just do `f(1000)`

Comment: Lets say n = 1200 in `f(n)`, `for x in range(1200)` when `x >= 1000` we don't add x in the total because of the problem instruction that only those numbers that are below 1000 will be included in the sum.

Comment: Why would you use 1200 if you want 1000? the point of using functions is so you don't need to repeat yourself, you can use it to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below ANY number, just pass it as its argument, if you really want only your case remove `def f(a):`  un indent the lines and where there is a `a` put `1000`

Comment: Your function has no protection of user values that might compromise the explicitly specified condition in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code:

1. First of all, `i = 0` is irrelevent to the rest of your code. All it's doing is defining `i` to be 0 after each iteration of the for loop.
2. Then, you are just taking the sum of the last number, because the other values are wiped out after each iteration.

So, what's the solution to this?

*Creating a list to append to, so you have access to each value in `a` iterations*:

```
l = []

def f(a):
    for i in range(a):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            l.append(i)
    print(sum(l))

f(100)
```

Output:

```
>>> 2318
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it has limit of 1000 and does not use a list.

```
def is_multiple(x, a):
    """Returns true if x is a multiple of a"""
    return x % a == 0


def f(a):
    total = 0

    for i in range(a+1):  # tests from 0 to 100 if a is 100
        if i >= 1000:
            break  # we don't process 1000 and above, get out of loop
        if is_multiple(i, 3) or is_multiple(i, 5):
            total += i  # increment our total variable
    
    return total


# Tests
n = 100
t = f(n)
print(f'num: {n}, total: {t}')
# num: 100, total: 2418

n = 1200
t = f(n)
num = f(n)
print(f'num: {n}, total: {t}')
# num: 1200, total: 233168
```